# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '01234SS'

Tags: python, django

I'll like to know, why I'm getting "invalid literal for int() with base 10 error" but works pretty well in the interactive mode?

```
fees = {u'nid':u'179', u'type':u'fees',  u'jamb_no': u'01234SS'}
    for fee in fees:
      # Transaction model
      try:
        txn = Transaction()
        txn.nid = int(fee.get(u'nid'))
        txn.type = options.get(u'type')
        txn.jamb_no = fee.get(u'jamb_no') # invalid literal for int() with base 10
        txn.save()
```

### Models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nid = models.IntegerField()
    jamb_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\celery\execute\trace.py"
, line 36, in trace
    return cls(states.SUCCESS, retval=fun(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\celery\app\task\__init__
.py", line 232, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery-2.3.2-py2.7.egg\celery\app\__init__.py",
 line 172, in run
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\transaction.py",
 line 217, in inner
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "api\tasks.py", line 142, in queue_transaction
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '01234SS'
```

on the interactive prompt, this works pretty well

```
>>> fees = {u'jamb_no': u'01234SS'}
>>> fees.get(u'jamb_no')
u'01234SS'
>>>

>>> jamb_no = u'01234SS'
>>> str(jamb_no)
'01234SS'
```

Please help me. I've been on this for 2 days.

Comment: Te interactive session you posted has nothig to do with your error, there you are using `str` and with something not defined 'jamb'

Comment: That was a typo. I have modified it. Also look closely at the first one.

Comment: check your code, if jamb_no is CharField should not be using `int` anywhere. Also check api/tasks.py line 42 and see what it is doing with `int`

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with celery. When I make changes to tasks.py, celery need to be restarted. This I didn't do, which obviously is causing a repetitive error messages even when the state has changed.